# Extract valid date from string using regx

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract valid date from string using regex in python.
I am using below example.

```
text='ï»¿2021 2021-02-18 14:03:54 0000-00-00 00:00:00 this is the string'
ts_pattern = r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}'
timestamps = re.findall(ts_pattern, text)
timestamps
```

But when I execute above code I am getting results "0000-00-00 00:00:00" along with valid date, please refer to below output. Can anyone let me know how I can exclude invalid date from search pattern.
Please advice.

```
timestamps
Out[160]: ['2020-07-17 14:03:54', '0000-00-00 00:00:00']
```

I was able to extract required date using below code.

```
text='ï»¿2021 2021-02-18 14:03:54 0000-00-00 00:00:00 this is the string'

pattern=re.compile('\\b\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2} \\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}\\b', re.IGNORECASE|re.MULTILINE)
find_date = re.search(pattern, text)

find_date.group(0)
Out[5]: '2021-02-18 14:03:54'
```

Comment: Regex alone is not the ideal tool for validating dates.

Comment: You need to validate the year, month, date, leap year, timestamp... etc, it's gonna be hell with regex.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen , I was able to extract expected results. I have attached updated code, Can you please check if approach seems to be correct

Comment: Follow the approach in the duplicate link.